# New tag proposition: Leetcode

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

[Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) is a very popular website for programming challenges. I would request that a new tag be created, [leetcode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leetcode), that can focus on these specific types of questions.

There has been an influx of Leetcode questions recently, that I have noticed, and this thought had crossed my mind.

I believe that, while [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) is a good tag, a tag created specifically for Letcode can help reviewers understand more about where the question originated from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forgive my bluntness, but absolutely not.

Today it's leetcode, yesterday it was hackerrank and tomorrow it might be who-knows-what. But what value does it add to know that by the tags? Are there leetcode experts with different experience than hackerrank experts?

Don't get me wrong: I'm in favour of questions stating where the problem came from. But that's already done and I don't see the added benefit of using tags for this. Keep in mind there's only room for 5 tags per question and enough questions are already at maximum usage.

Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer. But what is [leetcode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leetcode) going to add that [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) doesn't do already?

We used to do this. [exercism](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercism) for example, for questions from [exercism.io](https://exercism.io/). Do note that it's actually pointing towards [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) now.

Comment: I realized minutes after asking that multiple site specific tags already were synonyms of the programming-challenge tag. Doh!